# Plugin page active just in a store

Tags: magento-1.7

I have installed the plugin [Youtube Video Gallery](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/youtube-video-gallery-1.html) from magentocommerce.com. There seems to be a problem, I can acces the gallery page only from a store with the deafult package, but not from the one I have created. Also I enabled the Template Path Hints from admin, and I there isn't the plugin template file listed on the page. What could be the problem?

If needed any file listings just say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the gallery plugin installs it's template/skin files into `default/default` theme. This is wrong this has to be `base/deafult`.